# Merging two columns in hive and use between operator

Tags: hive

I have a login details table in hive with columns

**(DATE, TIME, USER)**

I am trying to write a query which can select users who have logged in between two dates with time also taking in consideration. For example: I want to know the users who have logged in between `10-12-2012` `02:30:00` and `28-12-2012` `16:20:00`. Dates in `DD-MM-YYYY` and Time in `HH:MM:SS` format.

I am able to execute

```
select * from test_table where time between "02:30:00" and "16:20:00" ;

select * from test_table where date between "10-12-2012" and "28-12-2012" ;
```

But i am not getting how to take both date and time columns into consideration while fetching the required result. Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
WHERE date BETWEEN "11-12-2012" AND "27-12-2012"
OR (date = '10-12-2012' and  time >= '02:30:00')
OR (date = '28-12-2012' and  time <= '16:20:00');
```

Comment: assume dates in DD-MM-YYYY and time in HH:MM:SS

Comment: Thanks david for replying i got the idea.