# AND clause not working in hive

Tags: sql, join, hadoop, hive

I have a table like idsfortime:

```
epochtime       id
1392951600  0
1392952500  15
1392953400  30
1392954300  45
1392955200  60
```

There is another table with the following columns :

```
15916B  5.1815954385269 1392977820
15965A  7.16797368783744    1392977880
16272B  10.6633890639568    1392977865
16707A  37.6028010736386    1392977785
16730A  9.42097617868767    1392977866
```

The last column in the above table denotes epoch time.

I am trying to find out those speeds (column 2 in above table) which lie between `epochtime` of table `idsfortime` and below table .

I am using the below query :

```
select t.speed from idsfortime t1 JOIN staging t where t1.epochtime >= t.time AND t1.epochtime <= t.time;
```

But, this doesnt work. Please suggest

Comment: You are checking for a condition which will never be true. t1.epochtime can not be lesser than 'AND' greater than t.time at the same time. Check your logic.

Comment: I think u are right. I am basically trying to use a BETWEEN clause here. I tried the following : select t.speed,t1.epochtime from idsfortime t1 JOIN (select MIN(t.time) as a,MAX(t.time) as b from staging t ) where t1.epochtime BETWEEN a AND b; But, this fails. Can you please suggest whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post.

[Merging two columns in hive and use between operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738227/merging-two-columns-in-hive-and-use-between-operator)

I hope you will resolve your issue. Keep in mind that while trying to use BETWEEN operator on DATE, the format should match to `DD-MM-YYYY` and TIME should match to `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: can i not use BETWEEN clause for epochtime? Moreover, whats wrong with the query?

Comment: what is the datatype of epochtime?? In the query you posted in Comments `where t1.epochtime BETWEEN a AND b` what exactly is a and b?

Comment: Datatype is string. Neels, what i am basically trying to do is find speed from table staging where the epochtime in table idsfortime lies between epochtime in table staging.