# Query Hive (SQL) between start of day and end of day

Tags: sql, datetime, hive

Given a date, I'd like to query Hive between the start and end of that day. How do I calculate the beginning and end of day in hive?

So instead of:

```
SELECT *
FROM blah
WHERE created_at > '1437940563' 
AND created_at < '1438026982';
```

It would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM blah
WHERE created_at > '<some function DATEID>' 
AND created_at < '<some function DATEID>';
```

Comment: did you try `FROM_UNIXTIME(TO_DATE(1438026982))` or something like that? http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html

Comment: Refer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738227/merging-two-columns-in-hive-and-use-between-operator